# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Speaker Recognition API - Verification - SpeakerInvalid

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to consume Microsoft Cognitive Speaker recognition API. I have attached Enrollment and verification audio samples. I get below response:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "SpeakerInvalid"
  }
}

Enrollment Audio : https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5qjjxvi16wdvs6/Enrollment.rar?dl=0
Verification Auidio : https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5q8prn2o0sqd2f/Verification.rar?dl=0

Comment: Did error happen in creating enrollment? or in verification step? Besides, please make sure if your audio file format meet the specific requirements. please check the links to get details about [Create Enrollment](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797) and [verify&authenticate users](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549d).

Comment: i am still facing same issue
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"SpeakerInvalid"}}'

code is attacted below

Answer (score 0):

That's a generic "I couldn't handle that audio" error. Your links are dead, so I can't check it. Make sure your audio meets the requirements:

- Container    WAV
- Encoding PCM
- Rate 16K
- Sample Format    16 bit
- Channels Mono

Demo web page here with the audio being encoded in a valid format: https://rposbo.github.io/speaker-recognition-api/

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues that we I have had is that the enrollment is not completed, so first check the status of the Enrollment. It should be Enrolled

```
Profile p = speakerIdClient.getProfile(UUid);
```